# Jquery-tools and fancybox conflict?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, jquery-tools

first off: i have no prior javascript or jquery experience.

I'm using Jquery-tools to create a tool tip on [this page](http://users.telenet.be/ezarto/ezarto/pco/tarieven.php) (the info icons) and fancybox to create an overlay on [this page](http://users.telenet.be/ezarto/ezarto/pco/index.php) (the "bel mij op" buttons).

Now, since i added the last lines of code to my script to trigger the tool tip, the tool tip works but fancybox stops working.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("a.iframe").fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': true
    });

    $('#tabs').tabs();

    $("td.tariefinfo img[title]").tooltip({
        'position': "center right"
    });

});
```

So i'm wondering if there's something wrong with my code (i haven't really figured out on how to see javascript errors with firegbug yet) or is it because both plugins are incompatible.

Thanks in advance.

Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the error in Firebug. Looks like you haven't include the "js/jquery.tools.min.js" file in http://users.telenet.be/ezarto/ezarto/pco/index.php yet.

```
$("td.tariefinfo img[title]").tooltip is not a function
```

Comment: Indeed that is the problem, thank you for sorting that out for me, guess i'm too tired.
Could you give a little more detail on how to see the error in Firebug please?

Comment: You can get it here and instal to Firefox. http://getfirebug.com/. Press F12 to open it. Then just end the tabs you want (Console, html, css, script, dom, net). After that open your page and you will get the error. You can take a look the Firebug website for more info. It's quite simple.